# Highcharts: Change the Legend TItle on drilldown

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to have the legend title change when I drill-down to the next level of the data.

Currently, I'm using a click event to call a function which removes the existing series and adds new ones, followed by chart.redraw().

Is it possible to set the Legend title using .attr in this same function?  I've seen a few examples that use this to change the y-axis or chart title, but I can't get it working for the legend title.

```
    function redrawLegend(legendtitle) {
    chart.legend.attr({
        text: legendtitle
        });
};
```

'legendtitle' is in this case a variable that I have stored with the drill-down data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use: `chart.legend.title.attr({ text: 'aaa' });`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ag6Wq/

Comment: If I want to retrieve the current title, `chart.options.legend.title.text` gives me the previous title, have to use `$(chart.legend.title.element).text()`. Not sure if this is the correct way?

Comment: It's perfectly fine. You can also use `chart.legend.title.element.childNodes[0].innerHTML` to get this without jQuery.